# ASP.NET Core OAuth not working with Safari

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, safari

We've recently discovered that something in the pipeline for OAuth (with both facebook/google) isn't working on desktop Safari (12.x and 13.x). The system is working fine for Chrome, Firefox and mobile Safari.

We're not sure when it broke but it was working 2 weeks ago and it wasn't working last night.

Here's where we configure OAuth in Startup.cs

```
.AddFacebook(options => {
                    options.AppId = SecretSettings.GetSecret("FacebookAppId");
                    options.AppSecret = SecretSettings.GetSecret("FacebookAppSecret");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth";
                    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token";
                    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler();
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name";
                    options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = remoteAuthTimeout;
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/login?returnUrl=%2F";
                })
                .AddGoogle(options => {
                    options.ClientId = SecretSettings.GetSecret("GoogleOAuth2ClientId");
                    options.ClientSecret = SecretSettings.GetSecret("GoogleOAuth2ClientSecret");
                    options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = remoteAuthTimeout;
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/login?returnUrl=%2F";
                })
```

And we generate the Challenge with this code:

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, authenticationScheme);
```

As best as we can tell the usual flow is:

1. Hit login with Google, generates a challenge token
2. Redirect to google oauth, user logs in and returns
3. Redirect to /signin-google (middleware route) to confirm the code given
4. Redirect to sso return action, handle the user login or registration

Chrome is hitting all of these correctly but Safari is getting stuck on 3. The browser doesn't get redirected back to our sso return action and instead is dropped off on the homepage of the site.

I inspected the urls involved and it looks like state, scope and code are being passed correctly, just something is happening internal to the middleware that kicks the user out to the root of the site.

We're using ASP.NET Core 3.0

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be going wrong? Or avenues we could explore to figure it out?

Comment: We haven't fixed it yet but our current thinking is that it's related to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/13746

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but is this something to do with ITP (Intelligent Tracking Prevention) and a missing user gesture when you try to do a redirect?
https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/

This type of thing is often introduced by vendors with very little consideration for those of us working with modern app security standards.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
I fixed it using the solution found here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18362

Add the SameSite cookie suggested code in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
});
```

And the following methods:

```
private void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
{
    if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
    {
        var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        if (DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
        {
            options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        }
    }
}
public static bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
{
    // Cover all iOS based browsers here. This includes:
    // - Safari on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - WkWebview on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - Chrome on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // All of which are broken by SameSite=None, because they use the iOS networking
    // stack.
    if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") ||
        userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Mac OS X based browsers that use the Mac OS networking stack. 
    // This includes:
    // - Safari on Mac OS X.
    // This does not include:
    // - Chrome on Mac OS X
    // Because they do not use the Mac OS networking stack.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") &&
        userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Chrome 50-69, because some versions are broken by SameSite=None, 
    // and none in this range require it.
    // Note: this covers some pre-Chromium Edge versions, 
    // but pre-Chromium Edge does not require SameSite=None.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will disable sending the samesite policy to browsers not compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None);
```

This solution is based on the thread https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4647.